# React: input onChange won't fire for the second time, first time it's work

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Recently I write my React JS app to import images from outside and process that image. In order to handle the user `onChange` event, I use onChange to run my function `handleChange`, but it won't work for the second time. How can I handle the `onChange` event properly?
Here is my code

```
         <div className={classes.fileUpload}>
            <div
              style={{
                position: "relative",
                display: "inline-block",
                height: "100%",
                width: "100%",
              }}
            >
              <input
                type={"file"}
                id="file"
                accept={"image/png, image/jpeg"}
                style={{ display: "none" }}
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.files)}
              />
              <label htmlFor="file" className={classes.labelFile}>
                <PublishIcon style={{ marginRight: "10px" }} />
                Upload file
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Are you choosing the same file the second time?

Comment: have u tried onInput?

Comment: Thank you, onInput its work <3 Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
import React from 'react'

class SimpleReactFileUpload extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      file:null
    }
  
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({file:e.target.files[0]})
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
        <h1>File Upload</h1>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} />
        
      </form>
   )
  }
}



export default SimpleReactFileUpload
```

hope it will work!

Comment: that kind of complicated way to do this. I tried onInput and its work, thank you btw